# How to loop through array inside an observable using async pipe?

Tags: angular, typescript

I am consuming an API which returns a response like this:

```
case:1
requests:[reqObj1,reqObj2,reqObj3]
count:3
message:"Found requests successfully."
pagesCount:1
```

The Service:

```
listRequest(sort, records, pageNumber, queries?): Observable<any> {
    const updateQueries = this.gtn.getHeaders() as RequestOptions;
    updateQueries.params = queries;
    return this.http
      .get(globals.domain + '/team/requests/list/sortBy-' + sort + '/' + records + '/' + pageNumber + '/', updateQueries)
      .map(res => {
        this.responseData = res.json();
        return this.responseData;
      });
  }
```

This will return an Observable with the response object as mentioned above, I will get this observable in the component and assign it to the local observable in the component.

Component:

```
this.requestResponse= this.rts.listRequest(sort, records, page, this.q);
```

I want to iterate over the array of request which is in the observable and i am using the async pipe in my html

HTML:

```
    <div class="request-items-inner" *ngFor="let request of requestResponse.requests | async">
{{request.createdAt}}
</div>
```

but this does not display anything on the screen. And if i use ***ngFor="let request of requestResponse| async"** it gives an error in the console.

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to unwrap the response with an 'async' pipe first, and then iterate over the requests array.

```
<div class="request-items-inner" *ngFor="let request of (requestResponse | async)?.requests">
  {{ request.createdAt }}
</div>
```

Comment: Awesome, Thank You!

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Comment: By the way, lets say i have a loading component, how can i use that while waiting for the data?

Comment: How to check if the data is returned by the Observable or data is empty before looping or unwrapping the observable??